# Where those variable come from in datastage

Tags: datastage

I have a User Variables Activity in datastage job like this.

name : start
expression : if start = "" then currentdate else @date

name : job
expression : dsjobname : "." : dsjobinvocationId

I'm curious about what the expression means

like Where @Date is come frome?

I couldn't find CurrentDateRT is come from?

also, where those DSJobName, DSJOBInvocationId variable come from?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what these expression mean.

In general, these are **programming components**. You can reach them via the expression editor menu:

[image]
[image]

RTFM: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=datastage-programming-components

> like Where @Date is come frome?

That is a **System Variable**. As you already guessed, it comes from the system.

RTFM: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=programming-system-variables

> I couldn't find CurrentDateRT is come from?

According to its name ending on RT and the way it's used in the code, this seems to be a custom **server routine**. This routine in particular did not come with DataStage but has been programmed by someone who maintained your project. You should be able to find the object in the projects objects repository (the tree view, use the search in the designer).

RTFM: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=datastage-working-routines

> also, where those DSJobName, DSJOBInvocationId variable come from?

These are **Job Status Macros**. They can be used in all active stages and before/after subroutines.

RTFM = https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=interfaces-job-status-macros

---

Have fun.